# IF condition when value is not 0 and not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula

```
=IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>0)),D2, IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>"")),D2,""))
```

and right now

- R29 is equal to 12+
- D16 is empty

But on the cell that my formula is at I get the value of D2 rather than an empty cell and I'm not sure why as I told the formula to show an empty cell if there is nothing on D16 and R29 = 12+.

Can somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the cell is empty, as opposed to having one or more whitespace characters? I would try `len(trim(D16))<>0` instead.

Comment: I would trim it down to just `=IF(AND($R$29="12+",LEN(TRIM(D16))<>0),D2,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excel if statement is `=IF (logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

in your code you switched the true with the false

so right now in the `=IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>0)),D2,IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>"")),D2,""))`

The first part returns true because `(AND($R$29="12+",D16<>0)` is actually true, so is does the true part of the statement witch is `D2`

The correct formula should be:

`=IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>0)),IF((AND($R$29="12+",D16<>"")),"",D2),D2)`